# Zeros of a linear combination

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functions

Suppose $f(z)$ is a complex valued function (continuous). Suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^j c_i [f(z)]^i =0 \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$ Does it follow that $f=0\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$? I think so but can't prove.

Note $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$ are assumed to be nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $j=1$ and $c_1=0$. Then $c_1f(z)=0$ for *every* function $f$.

Even if you assume that that $c_i$'s are non-zero, it is false. Take $f\equiv1$. Then $f-f^2=0$.

Comment: @Jake.F. Please see edit.

Comment: @Jake.F. Yes, of course. But that was *not* your question.

Comment: Because $f(\mathbb{C})$ is a subset of the zeros of a non-null polynomial, which is a finite set. But, since $f$ is continuous, $f(\mathbb{C})$ is connected. The only finite and non-empty connected sets are those with a single point.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is $f$ is restricted to the roots of $\sum_i c_i w^i$, which include $0$ iff $c_0=0$ and are limited to $0$ iff $c_i=c_j\delta_{ij}$.